# offline RGBD-SLAM can't generate transform

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,i'm new to ros ,i try to run rgbdslam offline from a bag,every thing seem to work fine,but the status bar show that the inliers always be 0.And the feature flow
image seem to do nothing.The node and edge could increase slowly.From the
terminal,i saw some output warning and repeat.
Could anyone help me out?

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_1.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_2.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_3.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_base.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_0.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_1.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_2.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_3.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_4.tfm for writing.

## WARNING:  Error: could not open transform file t_5.tfm for writing.

Inaddtionally,i can find some warn info in the log file:
such as
[WARN] You requested a transform that is 30593613421.786 miliseconds in the past,
but the most recent transform in the tf buffer is 30593613434.222 miliseconds old.
When trying to transform between /openni_rgb_optical_frame and /openni_camera.

[WARN] Using Standard kinect /openni_camera -> /openni_rgb_optical_frame as transformation

[WARN] Frame id /ground_truth_map does not exist! When trying to transform between /openni_camera and /ground_truth_map. - Using Identity for Ground Truth

[WARN] RANSAC found no valid trafo, but had initially 460 feature matches with average ratio 0.160627

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32881/offline-rgbd-slam-can%27t-generate-transform/) by [David B](https://answers.ros.org/users/2267/david-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the big warnings are something done by the icp library, shouldn't matter.
Also the other warnings shouldn't break things...

Have you tried another feature type?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thansk,Felix!I have fixed the problem! Originally, I used the sample.launch,it didn't work! When I used the rgbdslam.launch and
modified it to adjust the offline operation.Finally it works well.

---

Originally posted by [David B](https://answers.ros.org/users/2267/david-b/) with karma: 11 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1